# Scipy laplace scaling

Tags: scipy

I want to check the calculation of the `laplace` filter from `scipy.ndimage` and compare it to my own method if differentiation. Below I have a piece of code that I ran

```
import scipy.ndimage.filters
n = 100
x_range = y_range = np.linspace(-1, 1, n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

f_fun = X ** 2 + Y ** 2
f_fun_laplace = 4 * np.ones(f_fun.shape)
res_laplace = scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace(f_fun, mode='constant')
```

I expect that the variable `res_laplace` will have the constant value of `4` over the whole domain (excluding the boundaries for simplicity), since this is what I would get by applying the laplace operator to my function `f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2`.

However, the value that `res_laplace` produces is `0.00163` in this case. So my question was.. why is this not equal to 4?

Comment: not sure what you mean when you say you have an analytical solution?

Comment: ah sorry, what I mean that with the given function `f_fun` I should see a constant solution of 4. But instead I see a value of 0.01666 or something like that, which depends on the size of `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, in this specific case, is that you need to multiply the output of `scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace` with a factor of `(1/delta_x) ** 2`. Where `delta_x = np.diff(x_range)[0]`

I simply assumed that the filter would take care of that, but in hindsight it is of course not able know the value `delta_x`.
And since we are differentiating twice, we need to square the inverse of this `delta_x`.